# Pesquisa no DOM pelo name e value positivos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso pesquisar no DOM pelo name e value.
Estou tentando fazer assim

```
$('input[name=FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN value="{{ $cliente->FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN }}"]').attr('ckecked').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Porém não esta funcionando, no console aparece esta mensagem:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN value="M"]

Como resolver isto ?

Comment: Experimenta: `$('input[name="FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN"], input[value="{{ $cliente->FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN }}"]').attr('ckecked').trigger("chosen:updated");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você tem que separar as buscas dentro de colchetes diferentes:

```
$('input[name="FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN"][value="{{ $cliente->FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN }}"]').attr('ckecked').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

> [**Selector - Attribute Selectors**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)
>
> Multiple attribute selectors can be used to refer to several attributes of an element, or even several times to the same attribute.
>
> Here, the selector matches all `SPAN` elements whose "hello" attribute has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has exactly the value "Columbus":
>
> ```
> span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }
> ```

Ou em tradução livre:

> A seleção de múltiplos atributos no seletor pode ser usada para referenciar vários atributos de um elemento, ou até mesmo várias vezes o mesmo atributo.
>
> Aqui, o seletor combina todos os elementos `SPAN` em que o atributo "hello" tenha o exato valor "Cleveland" e o atributo "goodbye" tenha o exato valor "Columbus";
>
> ```
> span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

A sintaxe está errada, para usar [múltiplos](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) atributos é dessa forma:

```
$('input[name="FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN"][value="valor_aqui"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim:

```
$('input[name=FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN][value=FLG_SEXOX_CLIEN]:checked').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Não entendi muito bem o que você pretende fazer, pois me parece que está tentando atualizar o combo com o valor selecionado nele mesmo, se for esse o caso é só você fazer assim direto:

```
 $('#id-combo').trigger('chosen:updated');
```